# Compiling Vyper files results in a 'path exists outside base folder' error

Tags: truffle, vyper

I received a truffle compile error while compiling Vyper files

```
/VyperStorage.vy - path exists outside base folder
```

I was working with the truffle **VyperStorage Example Box**. When I execute `truffle compile` it shows me the error above. I have installed Vyper through pip. The truffle `config.js` file is used as default so no changes made to that either.